# thin served content inaccessible from certain connections

Tags: mac-osx, thin

I have a simple website being served up by the thin web server, on a machine running OSX mavericks. I'm able to access the served content on any machine that I try (both local and non-local connections). Similarly, the vast majority of my users, located around the country, can also access the content. However, a small subset of users simply get connection timeout errors trying to access the site. This problem seems to be connections/domain based since some users can access the site from a work connection, but not a home connections (using the same machine). I'm no sysadmin, and therefore have no idea what could be responsible for this kind of behavior. Is this most likely a server or client issue?

Comment: Are you really having people talk to thin directly, rather than reverse proxying from nginx or Apache?

Comment: I am really having people talk to thin directly...Is this a bad idea?